# I get this error when I run a .py file in vs code, it says something is not recognized , can anyone help me to fix that?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I get this error when I run a .py file in vs code:

```
n38-32" "c:/Users/hassan kh/Desktop/MY FOLDER/Python Projects/1_1.py"
& : The term 'C:/Users/hassan kh/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & "C:/Users/hassan kh/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32" "c:/Users/hassa ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:/Users/hassan...hon/Python38-32:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I deleted Python and vs code and installed it again but I get this error yet. if anyone knows or had this problem before, please let me know how can I fix it?

Comment: see if the executable exist and remove spaces from the path

Comment: thanks, can you explain a little more? when I write python in command prompt it says python is defined and shows the python version. but what do you mean by remove space from the path?

Comment: your user name has a space and the folder on the desktop has a space, use a different directory NOT on your desktop, just create a dir on your C: drive

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the path should be with backward slash \  in the path.

Comment: excuse me. I'm an amateur in vs code. can you explain more about how can I fix it?

Comment: the path of the directory  use this path ->  "c:\Users\hassan kh\Desktop\MY FOLDER\Python Projects\1_1.py" path in windows is followed by backward slash \ that is why you are geeting the error .